# Flash button not working in IE using wmode as transparent

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, hyperlink, wmode

I have a flash banner and css menu to use.

I tried flash with wmode as transparent for flash banner which makes the css menu to come over the flash banner.

but the button which is there in flash is not working in IE 7 and it's lower version.

any solution for this???

Answer (score 0):

Most sites suggest the use of
wmode="opaque"

This might solve your problem.
Using wmode="transparent" adds to more working for the browser to render some transparency, while opaque is best solution for it.